# How to split up NSArray into NSDictionary by array object's NSDate day of year?

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have a NSArray, and I sort it by its object's "published" property in descending order, newest first:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"published" ascending:YES];
NSArray *descps = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[sortDescriptor reversedSortDescriptor], nil];
[storiesLocal sortUsingDescriptors:descps];
[descps release];
[sortDescriptor release];
```

So now, I want to split this array up by each day, so that I can use it with a UITableView. In my example each date would be a tableview section header.
So if my example sorted array (storiesLocal) had dates like such:

```
2010-04-05 10:32:00
2010-04-05 06:20:12
2010-04-02 09:23:02
2010-04-02 03:20:34
2010-04-01 04:22:34
```

Then I would have tableview headers like "April 5", "April 2", "April 1". Therefore each would have 2, 2 and 1 row under each corresponding header

Essentially, my wanted outcome would be an NSDictionary. It's each key would be a date (2010-04-02), each value would be an NSArray of the correct objects to go with it. All of these should be sorted by date. Newest first.

I've gone through about 3 tries and failed every time, ending up deleting the code I wrote.

Edit: since an NSDictionary is an unordered list, it might be better to have an array of dictionaries, each dict including a key for the date and a key for the stories array, since order is very important.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't tested, but try something like:

```
NSArray *descps as above.

NSDateFormatter *in_formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDateFormatter *out_formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM d"];

NSString *todayStr =
[formatter release];

NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

for (ObjectType *obj in descps) {
  NSDate *date = [in_formatter dateFromString:[obj published]];
  NSString *day = [out_formatter stringFromDate:date];

  NSArray *array = [dict valueForKey:day];
  if (array == nil) {
    array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [dict setValue:array forKey:day];
    [array release];
  }

  [array addObject:obj];
}

[in_formatter release];
[out_formatter release];
```